# Should I use a singular or plural "one" here?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, pronouns, personal-pronouns, agreement

Sometimes I get confused over how and when we should use plurals.

For example, should we say:

> They are the only one who *is* capable
>   of doing this

Or

> They are the only one who *are*
>   capable of doing this

When to use is/are? Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"they are ... who is.." jars to me.

I'd prefer:

When talking about only one person or entity/organisation:

> He/she/it is the only one [who is]
>   capable of doing this

When talking about more than one person or entities:

> They are the only ones [who are]
>   capable of doing this

Answer (score 14):

When talking about only one person or entity/organisation:

> They are the only one who is capable of doing this

When talking about more than one person or entities:

> They are the only ones who are capable of doing this

Answer (score 1):

The construction can be boiled down simply to:

> **They are the only capable of doing this.**

*capable of doing* is an adjective phrase.

More obvious examples in the same direction would be:

> *Those maps are good, but the stamped ones are the only correct.*
>
> *I do not know where they all are. The only I could find is on the table.*

Similarly you can say "the best are/is", "the most are/is", "the nicest are/is"... as long as it is clear what subject you are referring back to. You can do this omission if the subject the word *one* or *ones* would refer to is close enough or to avoid repetition of *one* or *ones*.